# Regex to prevent ascending or descending sequence of more than 3 characters or digits

Tags: regex, logic

I have a regex

```
/^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

I would like to modify this to to prevent ascending or descending sequence of more than 3 characters or digits. I know this is not the most sensible solution but this is the requirement so I don't mind hard coding all the possible sequence.

Comment: give some examples..its not clear

Comment: I guess that's to ensure password complexity (current regex is *no sequence of 3 repeating digits, at least one digit, at least one upper case letter, and at least one lower case letter*), or something like that. And now you wan't to avoid stuff like `123` and `abc`? That's gonna be one *long* regex. It's possible, but you'd have to test for every sequence possible.

Comment: @ClasG If that's the case, then its not feasible to use regex

Comment: @rock321987 I agree :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution

```
/^(?!.*([0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*0123|.*1234|.*2345|.*3456|.*4567|.*5678|.*6789|.*3210|.*4321|.*5432|.*6543|.*7654|.*8765|.*9876|.*1122|.*2233|.*3344|.*4455|.*5566|.*6677|.*7788|.*8899|.*9900|.*0011|.*1100|.*(?i)qwerty|.*(?i)abcd|.*(?i)bcde|.*(?i)cdef|.*(?i)defg|.*(?i)efgh|.*(?i)fghi|.*(?i)ghij|.*(?i)hijk|.*(?i)ijkl|.*(?i)jklm|.*(?i)klmn|.*(?i)lmno|.*(?i)mnop|.*(?i)nopq|.*(?i)opqr|.*(?i)pqrs|.*(?i)qrst|.*(?i)rstu|.*(?i)stuv|.*(?i)tuvw|.*(?i)uvwx|.*(?i)vwxy|.*(?i)wxyz|.*(?i)zyxw|.*(?i)yxwv|.*(?i)xwvu|.*(?i)wvut|.*(?i)vuts|.*(?i)utsr|.*(?i)tsrq|.*(?i)srqp|.*(?i)rqpo|.*(?i)qpon|.*(?i)ponm|.*(?i)onml|.*(?i)nmlk|.*(?i)mlkj|.*(?i)lkji|.*(?i)kjih|.*(?i)jihg|.*(?i)ihgf|.*(?i)hgfe|.*(?i)gfed|.*(?i)fedc|.*(?i)edcb|.*(?i)dcba)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```