# How do I match the numbers sequence rising?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string contains just numbers. Something like this:

```
var numb = "5136789431235";
```

And I'm trying to match ascending numbers which are two or more digits. In string above I want this output:

```
var numb = "5136789431235";
//             ^^^^  ^^^
```

Actually I can match a number which has two or more digits: `/[0-9]{2,}/g`, But I don't know how can I detect being ascending?

Comment: Strange... Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691092/regex-to-prevent-ascending-or-descending-sequence-of-more-than-3-characters-or-d) that just was asked.

Comment: I think writing normal JS would be a much better option.Start with each digit of the the number and run a for loop over its length

Comment: So, it be ascend/descend one 1 only?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes ..! *(also just ascend not descend)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To match **consecutive** numbers like `123`:

```
(?:(?=01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89)\d)+\d
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3xR2/1)

---

To match **nonconsecutive** numbers like `137`:

```
(?:(?=0[1-9]|1[2-9]|2[3-9]|3[4-9]|4[5-9]|5[6-9]|6[7-9]|7[8-9]|89)\d)+\d
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pI2rK8/1)

---

Here is an example:

```
var numb = "5136789431235";

/* The output of consecutive version:    6789,123
   The output of nonconsecutive version: 136789,1234
*/
```

Comment: I think `\d` will suffice instead of `\d?`

Comment: @rock321987 thank you, that's right, `?` is not necessary here

Comment: @rock321987 Just as a note, I remember you said doing that by regex is impossible `;-)`, As a top user in regex tag, what you said is kinda odd..!

Comment: @Shafizadeh well, I was considering that the sequence can be in ascending order (like 1359) and not just there will be rise of 1

Comment: @rock321987 Ah, I see..!

Comment: @Shafizadeh that's why I asked ClasG, whether his solution will work for `168`..After that, it was made clear that the rise could only be of 1(in comments), though I should have asked that earlier

Comment: i didn't said it would not be possible, but it will not be feasible for this problem..anyway nice solution

Comment: Couldn't the first one be a lot shorter like this? : `(?:(?=01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89)\d)+\d` ? The Lookahead will match all numbers followed by a consecutive (at least one time) and then just take the next number?

Comment: @Falco that's right, and `((?=0[1-9]|1[2-9]|2[3-9]|3[4-9]|4[5-9]|5[6-9]|6[7-9]|7[8-9]|89)\d)+\d` for matching nonconsecutive numbers.

Comment: @Tim007 Nice edit ...! BTW enjoy it, you have earned almost 100 rep just for answering one of my question `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by simply testing for

```
01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89
```

Regards

Comment: what happens for number `168`

Comment: @rock321987 it shouldn't match at all.

Comment: Your pattern isn't completely correct, but maybe it could be a clue https://regex101.com/r/aZ9vY7/1

Comment: one thing that is still not clear, that there should be consecutive rise or not..that's why I raised the issue

Comment: @rock321987 Yeah .. they should be consecutive.

Comment: @Tim007 Nice one. I started looking at something similar, but quit because JS don't have look-behinds (for the last digit).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to loop through each number and check next one. Then add that pair of values to a result variable:

```
var numb = "5136789431235";
var res = [];
for (var i = 0, len = numb.length; i < len-1; i++) {
  if (numb[i] < numb[i+1]) res.push(new Array(numb[i],numb[i+1]))
}
res.forEach(function(k){console.log(k)});
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z80cjne1/)

Comment: Yes, I know, it works ... +1 ... But actually I wanted to match just those numbers which are ascend one 1. like this `123`, not this `135`.

Comment: oh sorry, then instead of checking numb[i] < numb[i+1] just check parseInt(numb[i])+1 == parseInt(numb[i+1]) here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1zh02fw/1/

Comment: Thanks, but still current result and expected result aren't the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to match consecutive numbers

```
var matches = [""]; numb.split("").forEach(function(val){ 
  var lastNum = 0;
  if ( matches[matches.length-1].length > 0 )
  {
    lastNum = parseInt(matches[matches.length-1].slice(-1),10);
  }
  var currentNum = parseInt(val,10);
  if ( currentNum == lastNum + 1 ) 
  { 
    matches[matches.length-1] += String(currentNum); 
  }
  else 
  { 
    if ( matches[matches.length-1].length > 1 ) 
    { 
       matches.push(String(currentNum)) 
    } 
    else 
    { matches[matches.length-1] = String(currentNum); 
    } 
  }
});
matches = matches.filter(function(val){ return val.length > 1 }) //outputs ["6789", "123"]
```

**DEMO**

```js
var numb = "5136789431235";

var matches = [""]; numb.split("").forEach(function(val){ 
  var lastNum = 0;
  if ( matches[matches.length-1].length > 0 )
  {
    lastNum = parseInt(matches[matches.length-1].slice(-1),10);
  }
  var currentNum = parseInt(val,10);
  if ( currentNum == lastNum + 1 ) 
  { 
    matches[matches.length-1] += String(currentNum); 
  }
  else 
  { 
    if ( matches[matches.length-1].length > 1 ) 
    { 
       matches.push(String(currentNum)) 
    } 
    else 
    { matches[matches.length-1] = String(currentNum); 
    } 
  }
});
matches = matches.filter(function(val){ return val.length > 1 }) //outputs ["6789", "123"]

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(matches,0,4);
```

Comment: @Shafizadeh Glad it worked for you. Good problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use Regex?

Not sure if the most efficient, but since they're always going to be numbers, could you split them up into an array of numbers, and then do an algorithm on that to sort through?

So like

```
var str = "123456";
var res = str.split("");
// res would equal 1,2,3,4,5,6
// Here do matching algorithm
```

Not sure if this is a bad way of doing it, just another option to think about

Answer (score 1):

I've did something different on a fork from *jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap* plugin, using substring method.

https://github.com/andredurao/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/commit/614ddf156c2edd974da60a70d4945a1e05ff9d8d

I've created a string containing the sequence ("123456789") and scanned the sequence on a sliding window of size 3.

On each scan iteration I check for a substring of the window on the string:

```
var numb = "5136789431235";
//check for substring on 1st window => "123""

"5136789431235"
          ˆˆˆ
```